# How to correctly return a list of dictionaries in Zapier Code (Python)?

Tags: zapier

The Zapier code documentation says that the output of a code zap can be either a dictionary or a list of dictionaries (See "Data Variable" section: https://zapier.com/help/code-python/).

When doing this,

```
output = [{'Booking':'Shirt'},{'Booking':'Jeans'}]
```

the output of the code returns only the first dictionary, however:

```
runtime_meta__duration_ms:  2
runtime_meta__memory_used_mb:   22
id: [redacted]
Booking:    Shirt
Fields with no value:
runtime_meta__logs
```

What am I doing wrong here? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

David from the Zapier platform team here. Code steps returning an array is a mostly undocumented (because there's no UI support and it's confusing, as you can tell) feature.

When testing, it'll only show the first item in the array. When it runs for real, all steps after the code step will run for each item in the array. The task history will reflect this

So set up the zap and turn on and it'll work like you expect.

Sorry for the confusion and let me know if you have any other questions!

Comment: This is still confusing to me and I really need help in understanding. I am losing faith in the docs at the time of this writing. Do we need to write a return statement with the output variable being returned? Do we set the variable output and don't have to worry about making a return statement? Does a variable named output need to be set or does that not matter? Can we return any variable as output or is that not how this works? The docs use the words return and output both programmatically and contextually. This at the source of my confusion.

Comment: sorry about the confusion. The answer is that both approaches work - Zapier runs a `return output` after your code runs (if the function hasn't already returned). So there are 2 options: 1. `return {'my': 'data'};` 2. `output = {'my': 'data'}`. Each are equivalent.

Comment: Thanks so much for your response years later. So, appreciative! This helps me out!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still looking for an answer to this questions, below is what find out returning list in Zapier.

```
# first import and convert your input value to an array.
# special note any line items imported into a python variable are converted to list format.
my_items = input_data['my_CSV_string']
my_list_of_items = my_items.split(",")

# Create a new list array 
my_new_list = []

length = len(my_list_of_items)
#Do all your computations    
for i in range(length): 
    my_new_list.append(float(my_list_of_items[i])*1.5)

# After completing any tasks you can return the list as follows, 
# If you are using line items keep the list in its original format
return {
    'my_processed_values': my_new_list,
    'original_values': my_list_of_items
}

# If you want to return it as a CSV "basically making the array flat"
my_old_CSV_list= ','.join(map(str, my_list_of_items))
my_new_CSV_list= ','.join(map(str, my_new_list))
return {
    'my_processed_cvs_values': my_new_CSV_list,
    'original_values': my_list_of_items
}
```

Hope this helps. I am not a Python expert but in theory the more lists used the longer the zap will take to process. Try to keep your python processing time to the lowest.

Best,