# Triggering multiple webhooks with Zapier array of Json objects

Tags: arrays, json, webhooks, zapier

I'm having trouble with triggering multiple webhooks via Zapier like [explained on Zapiers website](https://zapier.com/help/how-get-started-webhooks-zapier/#sending-an-array-of-objects) 
Did anyone manage to use this functionality?

I'm trying to create "an array of properly formed JSON objects".
To be able to select it as data source in the next step it needs to be a simple array (thats why I stringify the jsons inside the array).

Here is the json array I'm creating in Zapier Code trying to use to trigger two separate webhooks being triggered

```
var jsonArray = ['{"id":1,"data":111}','{"id":2,"data":222}'];

output = {jsonArrayOut: jsonArray};
```

[Here is a screenshot of a custom webhook request in Zapier](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uvdtL.png)

No matter how I format the data I always get one request, not two.

[This is the result I see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FekXi.png)

Could anyone please tell me what am I missing?

Comment: Don't stringify the json array, then the application won't be able to find the number of elements inside the string.

Comment: Also why is that you are wrapping the array into another object??

Comment: can you be a little more clear about what you're trying to do? Do you want one Code Step trigger to run subsequent actions multiple times?

Comment: @xavdid I want to change inventory levels in Shopify for orders we receive outside of Shopify. E.g. 
1. We get an order via email. 
2. This email will be parsed in Code, I will then get ids and quantity of the items I should deduct from shopify inventory
3. I want to fire a webhook to shopify for each of those items and decrease the inventory
For each of the items there needs to be a separate webhook. Shopify's API doesnt allow to do it in a single call. One inventory item - one call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cool, so what you described in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56624813/triggering-multiple-webhooks-with-zapier-array-of-json-objects#comment100155358_56624813) should totally be possible.

Your zap will be the following:

1. Trigger - new email
2. Parse email, return an array of `{id, data}` (see below)
3. Update inventory (will happen for each item in the array in step 2)

This takes advantage of an [undocumented](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47365005/1825390) feature of code steps where if they return arrays, the zap branches and subsequent steps run multiple times. Note that there's no UI for this and it'll look confusing, but it *will* work.

Your JS code will be something like the following:

```js
// parse email code
// get items and their quantities
// return object that looks like this
return [{id: 1, data: 123}, {id: 2, data: 456}]
```

In step 3 (however you're doing that), you'll be able to select `id` and `data` as mappable inputs. When you're setting the zap up, you'll only see `1` and `123` as options, but when the zap is on and runs for real, step 3 will get run for each array element returned in step 2.

Comment: Turns out there were multiple issues with my code.
For one I did want to return a string, not a JSON object. 
After I prepared the string (in line what @xavdid pointed out) I used JSON.parse() to convert it into a JSON object. Second issue I had I was using output instead of return.

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs:

> You can send an array of **properly formed JSON objects**, and we will
>   trigger the Zap once for each object in the array.

Application will be able to parse through the json and understand its structure. Making it as a string makes it to lose it.

So I'm guessing sending it as a string might not work. The Application won't be able to find the number of elements inside the string, it will consider entire string to be one element.

Try,

```
output  = [{"id": 1, "data": 111},{"id": 2, "data": 222}];
```

Comment: Thanks @arjithn 
When I pass the output as an array I'm unable to select the array as input for the next step - webhook.
http://prntscr.com/o2s2hn

Comment: When the output is an array, Zapier splits output into individual array elements, and I can only select those individual array elements, not the whole array as input for the webhook step. 
http://prntscr.com/o2s3nt

Comment: If you return an array it will always split up the outputs, as you have already noted. If you want access to all elements at one time you will have to return them all in a single object. That object will be mapped in the following step. Of course this will mean you will need a means of generating unique keys for each element within the object. The main issue with this is the following step will be expecting the same inputs consistently I imagine that will be difficult.